# Greasemonkey script is not clicking the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, click, greasemonkey

What is the problem here; it does not click?

My code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        premiumleech
// @namespace   premiumleech
// @include     http://generator.premiumleech.com/link/*.html
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

/*
<p class="leech-btn"><button onclick="javascript:window.open('http://generator.premiumleech.com/redir/BtPpnGJv2HcZRa2BTxsEQzUdDQbb6WO1','_blank');">Leech it!</button></p>
*/
/*
/html/body/div[2]/div/section/p[2]
*/

var targBtn = $("#content > p.leech-btn > button");
if (targBtn.length) {
targBtn[0].click ();
}
```

I tried JavaScript first, but failed to adapt it as `queryselector` "could not find any word on that button Weired" and get..ByTagName failed for no apparent reason at least to me

```
function clickc()
{
var el = document.querySelector("_blank"); or document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE");
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            false, false, false, false,
            0, null);
el.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Comment: `.click()` should work just fine. Are you getting a element from that `$("body > div:second > div:first > div:first > p:second")`?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's click() method doesn't fire the click action on elements. It triggers the actions which are registered for the click event handlers instead and if arguments are passed, it's used as callback functions for click on that element. For clicking that HTML element you need to use

```
$("body > div:second > div:first > div:first > p:second").get(0).click();
```

This will essentially select the HTML Element (not the jQuery Object) and fire the click event.

Comment: Did Not Work The Link i tested is this 
http://generator.premiumleech.com/link/qBtrxQmWvMr9y7XbcPSv87qNsbpjDVbs.html